# Vonnegutian Imperative: Replace semicolons with periods *correctly*

Tags: regex, linux, text, sed

This question is a little tongue-in-cheek, but I'm also seriously curious as to the proper and cleanest way to do this.

Background: Kurt Vonnegut said that semicolons are worthless pieces of punctuation. All they do is show that you've been to college.

Anyways, I know that if I have a text (e.g., "test.txt") file with a bunch of worthless semicolons separating "closely related" sentences, I can do a find and replace with:

```
sed 's/;/./g' <test.txt >better.txt
```

Which will replace all those pesky semi-colons with periods. However, now I have problem that all the new periods are followed by words without the first letter capitalized (since one does not capitalize a word after a semicolon).

Is there a way (hopefully via sed) to automatically replace all the semicolons in a text file with periods AND also automatically capitalize the first letter of the words following the newly inserted periods?

Thanks,
hft

Comment: Think about a semicolon at the end of a line.

Comment: I was using semicolons long before I went to college.

Comment: @!maynard: You were precocious in your pretension. Good for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer. Yes, absolutely.

Here is a way using GNU `sed`:

```
$ echo "hello;world;i;am;here" | sed 's/;\(.\)/.\U\1/g'
hello.World.I.Am.Here
```

For the standard prose case of semi-colons followed by a space use:

```
$ echo " Hello; world; blah" | sed 's/; *\(.\)/. \U\1/g'
Hello. World. Blah
```